# Why does a comma not work in variable assignment but does in print()

Tags: python

```
my_name = "Ali"
my_age = 22
place_of_work = " TD Bank"

introduction = 'Hi, my name is ' + my_name + ' and I am' , my_age , 'years old.' + ' I work at' +  place_of_work + '.'

print (introduction)
```

It prints with brackets and quotations. It works well when I change the variable introduction to print() but I just wanted to know why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Watch where you have commas and where you have plusses

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp because Introduction is storing it as a variable which does not have `,` support because its not a way to concatenate a string while the print statement allows you to do that because it is converting everything to a string prior to printing out the text you want.

Comment: Or use `print (*introduction)` to unpack the tuple in `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings via the method you used but because my_age is an int, it will not concatenate with the strings. Replace with:

```
introduction = 'Hi, my name is ' + my_name + ' and I am' + str(my_age) + 'years old.' + ' I work at' +   place_of_work + '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

In some places you use commas and some places you use "+", replace commas with the + sign and it should work.